# I need to get all properties of taxonomy termstrore. which I already get are "Label","WSSId","TermGuid" but I need to get Other labels as well

Tags: spfx, term-store, react, typescript, pnp-js-core

Is there any solution to get other properties for taxonomy termstore. As I remember, I usually used "include" to get all properties which I mentioned in JSOM. But now I need to work by using Typescript cause I am working on SPFX and React.

Does anyone know how to include here?

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.
getByTitle("listName")
.items.select("taxonomyField/Label" , "Title").
expand("taxonomyField").get()
  .then((answer: any) => {
      return answer;
  })
```